# Scraping ajax xmlhttprequest using python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrape school name, address, phone, email in UK from https://www.isc.co.uk/schools/ this website using xmlhttpeequest. It returns error 500.

```
import requests
headers = {"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*","Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
"Cookie": "_ga=GA1.3.1302518161.1584461820; _hjid=5f23e8d2-23c6-4c87-9cc0-ca216b587ae1; cookie_preference=false; iscFilterStates=%7B%22locationLatitude%22%3Anull%2C%22locationLongitude%22%3Anull%2C%22distanceInMiles%22%3A0%2C%22residencyTypes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22genderGroup%22%3Anull%2C%22ageRange%22%3Anull%2C%22religiousAffiliation%22%3Anull%2C%22financialAssistances%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22examinations%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22specialNeeds%22%3Afalse%2C%22scholarshipsAndBurseries%22%3Afalse%2C%22latitudeSW%22%3A47.823214345168694%2C%22longitudeSW%22%3A-18.049563984375%2C%22latitudeNE%22%3A59.385618287793505%2C%22longitudeNE%22%3A12.953853984375021%2C%22contactCountyID%22%3A0%2C%22contactCountryID%22%3A0%2C%22londonBoroughID%22%3A0%2C%22filterByBounds%22%3Atrue%2C%22savedBounds%22%3Atrue%2C%22zoom%22%3A5%2C%22center%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3A54.00366%2C%22lng%22%3A-2.547855%7D%7D; _gid=GA1.3.1000954634.1584850972; _gat=1; __atuvc=11%7C12%2C4%7C13; __atuvs=5e773c3c593ef6aa000; __atssc=google%3B7",
"Host": "www.isc.co.uk",
"Origin": "https://www.isc.co.uk",
"Referer": "https://www.isc.co.uk/schools/",
"Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
"Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3927.0 Safari/537.36"}

response = requests.post('https://www.isc.co.uk/Umbraco/Api/FindSchoolApi/FindSchoolListResults?skip=20&take=20', headers = headers)

response.status_code
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The website is loaded with `JavaScript` event which render it's data dynamically once the page loads.

`requests` library will not be able to render `JavaScript` on the fly. so you can use `selenium` or `requests_html`. and indeed there's a lot of modules which can do that.

Now, we do have another option on the table, to track from where the data is rendered. I were able to locate the [XHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) request which is used to retrieve the data from the `back-end` `API` and render it to the users side.

> You can get the `XHR` request by open [Developer-Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and check [Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) and check `XHR/JS` requests made depending of the type of call such as `fetch`

```py
import requests
import csv

data = {'locationLatitude': None, 'locationLongitude': None, 'distanceInMiles':
        0, 'residencyTypes': [], 'genderGroup': None, 'ageRange': None, 'religiousAffiliation': None, 'financialAssistances': [], 'examinations': [], 'specialNeeds': False, 'scholarshipsAndBurseries': False, 'latitudeSW': 47.823214345168694, 'longitudeSW': -18.049563984375, 'latitudeNE': 59.385618287793505, 'longitudeNE': 12.953853984375021, 'contactCountyID': 0, 'contactCountryID': 0, 'londonBoroughID': 0, 'filterByBounds': True, 'savedBounds': True, 'zoom': 5, 'center': {'lat': 54.00366, 'lng': -2.547855}}

r = requests.post(
    "https://www.isc.co.uk/Umbraco/Api/FindSchoolApi/FindSchoolListResults?skip=0&take=20", json=data).json()

with open("data.csv", 'w', newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["Name", "Address", "Phone", "Email"])
    for item in r:
        writer.writerow(
            [item["Name"], item["FullAddress"], item["TelephoneNumber"], item["EmailAddress"]])
    print("Done")
```

Output : [View-Online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/cafc3c70bfa97d6b3b4a7574f8130490/data.csv)

[image]